# why are there misleading ads on askubuntu?

Tags: discussion

Tonight when visiting askubuntu.com I encountered a chat window that asked me whether I wanted to chat with an expert. Strangely it had a hint that a transcript of this session would be available (posting the link here is not allowed, but it was from adviza.stackexchange.com)

I have no idea, what this ad is supposed to be for, clearly it was a bot talking. Whatever it's for, or does, I think that kind of advertisement has no place on this site. What do you think?

Comment: Related on MSO: [What is “chat with an expert”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert)

Comment: fun game: Copy/paste the response from the bot and see how long it takes for it to get stuck in an infinite loop. Challenge: Who can get the largest loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## April fool day wishes :p

It is an april fool message from stack exchange, Enjoy ;)

Comment: Anyone else immediately click "Never" when they saw the pop up?